# Setting and Retrieving metadata of blob in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata) mentions about storing and retrieving metadata at container level. I was just wondering if its possible to set and retrieve metadata about a blob stored in a directory inside that container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was just wondering if its possible to set and retrieve metadata
>   about a blob stored in a directory inside that container?

Yes, you can certainly do so. Please see the sample code below:

```
        const string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key";
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);

        //Create the service client object for credentialed access to the Blob service.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("images/logo.png");
        blob.FetchAttributes();//Gets the properties & metadata for the blob.
        blob.Metadata.Add("Key", "Value");
        blob.SetMetadata();//Saves the metadata.
```

Comment: Thanks! I am glad I checked this post again coz I was disheartened when you initially said that it was not possible.

Comment: Sorry....my bad! I read the post incorrectly. I thought you wanted to set metadata on the folder. Once I reread the question, I realized my mistake and edited my answer. Sorry about that!